# How can i convert a file .png to a Bitmap? Nothing works for me. Error "'Failed to decode image. The provided image must be a Bitmap.'" Xamarin.forms

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, bitmap

I'm working with **Xamarin in the part of  Xamarin.Forms**  i need to convert a file ("image.png") to a Bitmap because when project run its enter in "break mode" and show me this message "Java.Lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'Failed to decode image. The provided image must be a Bitmap.'". So i tried to convert the file in many ways like:

1_ Using methods from System.Drawing.Bitmap but it's show this exception "This operation is not supported in this platform"

2_ Cannot use Android.Graphics because i'm working in xamarin.forms not in xamarin.android.

3_ I tried to convert the "image.png" into a base64 or byte[] array and then into a bitmap but the problem is the same like in first problem because to convert from byte[] array or base64 to a Bitmap i have use methods from System.Drawing.Bitmap.

4_ I tried using the library SkiaSharp but i don't have success because i don't found so much information  about how to convert .png to SKBitmap and then convert SKBitmap to Bitmap (even i don't know if this is possible).

5_ Finally i converted "image.png" to a "image.bmp" with an app and use the file .bmp in my project but it doesn't work too.

the "image.png" i have to save in a string variable, well that's the idea.

If you have a solution with SkiaSharp o whatever i will glad

**EDIT**

here is a part of my code, i just save in a variable the image

```
Icon = "pin_blue.png";
//i can't use a path because in xamarin you have many size from the same 
//image for the different size of the screen
```

**EDIT 2** This is my method to show the pins in google maps

```
private void ShowPins(List<PointsOfInterest> resultPointsOfInterest)
        {
            if (resultPointsOfInterest != null && resultPointsOfInterest.Any())
            {
                var location = Geolocation.GetLastKnownLocationAsync();
                PointsOfInterest position = new PointsOfInterest();
                if (location != null)
                {
                    position.ccsm0166latitud = location.Result.Latitude;
                   position.ccsm0166longitud = location.Result.Longitude;
                
            }
            else {
                position = resultPointsOfInterest.First();
            }
            //Distance = Distance.FromKilometers(new Random().Next(23,35));
            Distance = Distance.FromKilometers(3);
            Position = new Position(position.ccsm0166latitud, position.ccsm0166longitud);
            PinsFiltered= Pins = new List<PinCustom>(resultPointsOfInterest.Select(
                x => new PinCustom()
                {
                    Position =
                        new Position(x.ccsm0166latitud, x.ccsm0166longitud),
                    Address = x.ccsm0166direccion,
                    Label = x.ccsm0166nombre,
                    Type = PinType.Place,
                    TypePointOfInterest = x.ccsm0166tipositio,
                    IconBM = Int32.Parse(x.ccsm0166tipositio) == (int)PointOfInterestType.branch ?  PinCustom.ConvertToBitmap("pin_blue.png") :
                        Int32.Parse(x.ccsm0166tipositio) == (int)PointOfInterestType.branch ? "pin_blue.png" :
                        Int32.Parse(x.ccsm0166tipositio) == (int)PointOfInterestType.branchWithExtendedHours ? "pin_black.png" :
                        Int32.Parse(x.ccsm0166tipositio) == (int)PointOfInterestType.branchWithExtendedHours2 ? "pin_black.png" :
                        Int32.Parse(x.ccsm0166tipositio) == (int)PointOfInterestType.branchWithExtendedHours3 ? "pin_black.png" :
                        Int32.Parse(x.ccsm0166tipositio) == (int)PointOfInterestType.selfServiceTerminal ? "pin_green.png" :
                        Int32.Parse(x.ccsm0166tipositio) == (int)PointOfInterestType.atmServBox ? "pin_yellow.png" : string.Empty
                }).ToList());
        }
        else
        {
            Pins = new List<PinCustom>();
        }
    }
```

This is the class Pin where i save the image

```
public class PinCustom : Pin
    {
        public string TypePointOfInterest { get; set; }
        public string Icon { get; set; }
        public Bitmap { get; set; }
        //Here  i create this variable to save a bitmap but i don't know if i do the things well
    }
```

this is the icon .png i want to show in googlemaps

[Pin Blue Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LB6OD.png)

Comment: what are you doing in your project that requires a bitmap instead of a standard jpg/png file?  Android and iOS both support PNG as a standard format.

Comment: A PNG file __is__ a Bitmap. You don't really talk about the BMP file format? Always make sure to not confuse terms..!

Comment: @Jason i try to put pins in google maps, i have 5 types of pins (pins are the image .png) when i put the pins in format .png the app enter in mode break and show the error i said at the beginning, that's the reason i tried to convert image.png to Bitmap

Comment: you can use PNG for Google Maps pins

Comment: @TaW the error said "Failed to decode image. The provided image must be a Bitmap" so i tried to convert .png to Bitmap, but anyway i tried using the format .bmp too.

Comment: @Jason no, i can't. when i use "image.png" the app enter in break mode and show "Failed to decode image. The provided image must be a Bitmap". This is mi code:   Icon = "pin_blue.png";

Comment: a single line of code does not provide enough context to understand what you are doing.  I'd suggest you either edit the question to focus on the actual problem you have, or delete it and add a new question.  This has absolutely nothing to do with converting a png to a bitmap.  There also many existing questions about the specific error message you are getting

Comment: _Failed to decode image. The provided image must be a Bitmap_ The only way for this to makke sense I can think of would be that the image is in fact not a bitmap raster image but a e.g. vector format, which png can't be afaik. So maybe the image is misnamed. Or the error message is misleading. (They often are..) In GDI a wrong (ie not supported ) pixelformat can lead to varous misleading error messages.  Can you post the image?

Comment: @TaW i upload the image, do you have a contact? i can't send message by stack because i'm new

Comment: @Jason i edit my comment with some code for a better resolution

Comment: Have you read the Xamarin docs and sample showing exactly how to do this?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/map-pin

Comment: yes @Jason, but just in my case i can't use BitmapDescriptorFactory or any method about System.Drawing.Bitmap because mi platform not support that operations and that the reason i'm stuck

Comment: Nowhere does it mention `System.Drawing.Bitmap`.  It does use `BitmapDescriptorFactory` in the **Android specific** part of the instructions.  Please download the sample app and see how it works.

Comment: Hi! i was able to find the error, it has nothing to do with the bitmap or something else. the error was the image.png was not referenced in the Resource.Designer.cs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To open your file and convert it to byte array:

```
string directory = Path.Combine(Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath, Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDownloads); 
// or your image directory, just replace it
var stream = File.OpenWrite(Path.Combine(directory, "image.png"));
byte[] buff = ConvertStreamToByteArray(stream);
stream.Close();

public static byte[] ConvertStreamToByteArray(Stream stream)
        {
            byte[] byteArray = new byte[16 * 1024];
            using (MemoryStream mStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                int bit;
                while ((bit = stream.Read(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length)) > 0)
                {
                    mStream.Write(byteArray, 0, bit);
                }
                return mStream.ToArray();
            }
        }
```

then, to pass this byte array to SKBitmap:

```
SKBitmap bmp = SKBitmap.Decode(buff);
```

EDIT:

If you want to try without `ConvertStreamToByteArray()`:

```
byte[] buff = null;
stream.Write(buff, 0, buff.Length);
```

This `Write` will depend of the type of your `stream`. In this example, I'm using `FileStream`.

EDIT 2:

```
string resourceID = "image.png";
Assembly assembly = GetType().GetTypeInfo().Assembly;

using (Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceID))
{
   resourceBitmap = SKBitmap.Decode(stream);
   SKBitmap bmp = SKImage.FromBitmap(resourceBitmap);
}
```

and then you can use this bitmap to draw and fill your SKCanvas:

```
canvas.DrawBitmap(bmp, 0, 0);
```

Comment: I'm sorry but i can use Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath or Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDownloads i am in the part of xamarin.forms i think that library is in the part of xamarin.android

Comment: @vansh1R I commented on the answer that `or your image directory, just replace it`, you just need to set this as your directory that you not mentioned. I don't know if you have a root, e.g: C:\Users\test\Download\image.png or another different.

Comment: You can use `Device.RunPlatform` to get the folder in Android and IOS. See this link: https://startdebugging.net/2019/07/xamarin-forms-using-onplatform/

Comment: i can't use a path becasue i have the image in many size (that is how xamarin works ) so y just put the name of the file, this is my code:   IconBM = "pin_blue.bmp" ;

Comment: Did you mean that your image is inside your Xamarin project? If so, then you don't need to get it from a file, you can just create a `Image` and set its source, e.g: `Image img = new Image() { Source = "image.png" }`.

Comment: My example shows how to get a local .png image, read, convert to byte and then convert to SKBitmap. In the title of your question is ".png", not ".bmp", and its "File", not "drawable folder" or something like that.

Comment: oh you're right, i'm so sorry, was my error i used the wrong words, thank you

Comment: No problem. I will edit my question with an alternative solution of it. Check and test, please.

Comment: do you have a contact? i can't send message you because mi account is new. I tried your code and i have error in the last line, error said "Cannot implicity convert type Skimage to SKBitmap" Edit from last comment

Comment: @vansh1R send me your e-mail here, please.

Comment: Hi! i was able to find the error, it has nothing to do with the bitmap or something else. the error was the image.png was not referenced in the Resource.Designer.cs, now i just have to reference that image and everything gonna work! thanks a lot for your support and pattience!

Answer (score 0):

Use ffmpeg
command for this: ffmpeg -i image.png image.bmp

Comment: It looks like the question was asked for a specific implementation in Xamarin and not how to convert .png to a bitmap in general. Please specify how OP can use your answer within Xamarin.

Comment: thanks for your answer but i need to use code in this ocation, something like
 **Bitmap bm = new Bitmap("image.png");** but obviously in other way hehe

Answer (score 0):

> i have 5 types of pins (pins are the image .png) when i put the pins
> in format .png

if you want to custom the pins in your map, you can simply use [Custom Renderers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/) to achieve this.

The icon used to represent a marker can be customized by calling the `MarkerOptions.SetIcon` method. This can be accomplished by overriding the `CreateMarker` method, which is invoked for each Pin that's added to the map:

```
protected override MarkerOptions CreateMarker(Pin pin)
{
    var marker = new MarkerOptions();
    marker.SetPosition(new LatLng(pin.Position.Latitude, pin.Position.Longitude));
    marker.SetTitle(pin.Label);
    marker.SetSnippet(pin.Address);
    marker.SetIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.FromResource(Resource.Drawable.pin));
    return marker;
}
```

If you want to display different icons, you can  refer to the following code:

```
protected override MarkerOptions CreateMarker(Pin pin)
    {
        var marker = new MarkerOptions();
        marker.SetPosition(new LatLng(pin.Position.Latitude, pin.Position.Longitude));
        marker.SetTitle(pin.Label);
        marker.SetSnippet(pin.Address);
        var customPin = (Element as CustomMap).CustomPins.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Position == pin.Position);
        if (customPin != null)
        {
            if (customPin.IconType == "corporate")
            {
                marker.SetIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.FromResource(Resource.Drawable.corporate));
            }
            else if (customPin.IconType == "pickup")
            {
                marker.SetIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.FromResource(Resource.Drawable.bus));
            }
        }

        return marker;
    }
```

For more, check:[Customizing the Marker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/map-pin#customizing-the-marker).